# Can you spend your time just walking around in Animal Crossing?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My three-year-old daughter loves to just walk around the landscape of whatever game I've got in my Nintendo Switch at the time, which is great, but I'm trying to play LoZ: Skyward Sword at the minute and she's getting frustrated at the bats flying around and hitting her in the head and it's stopping me progressing out of the Knights Academy where she seems to be "safe" to walk around...

I had the thought that I could just buy Animal Crossing: NH for her since my understanding of the game is you're just managing your own little village (I've never played one!) so I was hoping she'd just be able to walk around this little village to her hearts content without some NPC interrupting her merry little path...

Is this the case or are there similar fiendish interruptions that would annoy her?

Comment: Minecraft on Nintendo Switch can work wonders for that. Put it on Creative Mode and let your kid roam around and punch blocks to their heart's content. It has a Mario-themed map that is very pretty, and a few other fun ones, too.

Comment: Alba: A Wildlife Adventure is 100% peaceful and is good for just walking around, since a large part of the game is exploring and watching animals. I recently got it on Switch for some younger kids and was happy with it.

Comment: @februaryInk - thanks, I've downloaded Alba onto my phone and shes enjoying that too!

Comment: Hi, also if you ever want to look for more games where you daughter can just walk around, look for the genre "Walking Simulators" it should have some good ones.  Hope this helps if you need it.  =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Animal Crossing New Horizons *does* have scorpions that walk on the ground, as well as spiders that fall from shaken trees. However, the scorpions won’t kill, they will only make the player faint, and make the player respawn at their house, no matter where they fainted on the island. I do believe there are some sort of “spawn condition” for these dangerous critters that I am not aware of…

I think you should be safe if you just stay in the village, but I can’t be 100% certain.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 10):

As previously mentioned, there is minimal danger from just walking around your island  apart from mildly dangerous bugs. Spiders and scorpions both only spawn at night (real time), so if this is a problem then you could set your Switch's internal clock to daytime again and the bugs go away.

Wasps can occasionally appear when a tree is shaken, which may happen at any time of day. These flying annoyances can sting your character the same way a spider or scorpion would. They only appear when their nest happens to be shaken loose from their tree, unlike their creepy crawly counterparts which merely spawn at night.

For your daughter I think is Animal Crossing is an excellent and safe game, but just be aware that the game requires you to build your island from the ground up - so there may be little for her to do on the small island, and activities are especially limited for the first 24 hours (real time) while your character settles in.

If you wish, you can read  more about the three dangerous critters of Animal Crossing [here](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2020-03-20-animal-crossing-bee-wasp-stings-medicine-new-horizons-7018).

Comment: I think the perfect way to play with a 3 year old would be to have the adult play (and managing the island building business), and have the child be a guest (its one island per switch, and switch account that logs in after is a guest that has only the basics of walking around, fishing, talking, etc.)

Comment: This question (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365441/can-you-have-2-different-islands-on-the-same-switch) has details about what is blocked or not for the guest player, but a Question could be added to completely list what is blocked/available for the guest.

Comment: I'm happy to do the building of the island so she has something different to walk around every so often :) and @Fredy31 - That sounds perfect except for some reason she never uses her own account on the switch even if i log in on her account before hand lol, im sure other people will find that useful of course!

Comment: In any way, even if shes not on her own account, there's not much truly destructive stuff you could do in ACNH

Comment: @Sayse I suspect if you have her create a character, and show her YOUR character's house, and send her letters from YOUR character to HER character, she'll quickly want to use her character!  Plus the clothing items and such.

Comment: @Joe - That sounds amazing for most parents, however the one detail I didn't include in my post is she's autistic and communicating tasks like that are a little difficult at her current age :)